# Using PySoundFile, how can I get a buffer of bytes?

Tags: python, buffer, soundfile

I am trying to load an audio file (via `PySoundFile`) and have it return a buffer of `bytes`. But current `dtype`'s are `['float32', 'float64', 'int16', 'int32']`

I need it as `bytes` to use with `pocketsphinx`: `decoder.process_raw`

Comment: If you want a buffer of `bytes`, why not just opening it as `open(path, "rb")`?

Comment: I need to use `PySoundFile` to get some other info about the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
audio_data = self.SOUND_FILE.read(sample_frames, dtype='int16')
audio_bytes = audio_data.tobytes()
```